# How to use captcha before page load in laravel?

Tags: laravel, recaptcha, captcha

on my Laravel project, I want to use captcha before a page becomes visible. I am explaining it a little bit more.

imagine, we will go to `https://www.example.com/test`
we have to solve the captcha to view this page content.

Can anyone help me or give me proper guidelines to do this?

Comment: build a middleware that will handle the captcha.

Comment: can you please explain more, or give some reference or demonstration?

Comment: Well you... search the internet for *laravel captcha middleware* for example.